# Why element wise division between two dataframes with one column each result in NaN and two columns?

Tags: python, dataframe, nan, division

```
import pandas as pd

df0 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [864371.0, 864383.0, 864364.0, 864381.0, 864364.0]})

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'b': [867318.0, 867315.0, 867323.0, 867331.0, 867327.0]})

df0/df1
    a   b
0 NaN NaN
1 NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN
3 NaN NaN
4 NaN NaN
```

Why am i not getting an element wise division?

I was expecting an element wise division

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/995714)

Comment: I think the main issue is that the columns need to have the same name, if you're doing that

Answer (score 2):

In general, when you have an operation between dataframes like this, pandas aligns the axes before doing the operation. This means that it will not just divide any element from df1 by any element from df2 that appears to be in the same position. Instead, it will divide any element from df1 by that element from df2 which has the same index value and the same column name.

In your example, both dataframes have the same index, so the index alignment works as you expected. But the column names are different. So to get the result you expected, either rename one of the columns to the column name from the other dataframe, as Mark suggested, or explicitly divide the one series by the other:

```py
df0.a / df1.b
```

```
0    0.996602
1    0.996619
2    0.996588
3    0.996599
4    0.996584
dtype: float64
```